# How do I solve the error for the build gradle project?

Tags: java, android, firebase, build.gradle

I am trying firebase for my app but when I put the necessary scripts/plugins and sync it.
It gives me an error for my project gradle file:

```
Build file 'D:\UCLL\3de jaar\app_Comic\build.gradle' line: 6

Could not compile build file 'D:\UCLL\3de jaar\app_Comic\build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  build file 'D:\UCLL\3de jaar\app_Comic\build.gradle': 6: all buildscript {} blocks must appear before any plugins {} blocks in the script
```

my project build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.0' apply false
}
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository
    }
}
```

my build.gradle app:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.mowmow'
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mowmow"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0'

    //picasso
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.8'

    //ToStringBuilder
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.4'

    //Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'

    //Firebase/google
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
}
```

but when I put the plugin in the middle it gives me an other error:

```
Build file 'D:\UCLL\3de jaar\app_Comic\build.gradle' line: 18

A problem occurred evaluating root project 'app_Comic'.
> Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'Google' was added by build file 'build.gradle'

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'app_Comic'. <87 internal lines>
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:116)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:42) <82 internal lines>
Caused by: org.gradle.api.InvalidUserCodeException: Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'Google' was added by build file 'build.gradle' <11 internal lines>
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor153.invoke(Unknown Source) <6 internal lines>
    at build_63utr2332008u9gjv762bsg3t$_run_closure1$_closure2.doCall(D:\UCLL\3de jaar\app_Comic\build.gradle:18) <18 internal lines>
    at build_63utr2332008u9gjv762bsg3t$_run_closure1.doCall(D:\UCLL\3de jaar\app_Comic\build.gradle:17)<47 internal lines>
    at build_63utr2332008u9gjv762bsg3t.run(D:\UCLL\3de jaar\app_Comic\build.gradle:16)<1 internal lines>
    ... 170 more
```

script:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.0' apply false
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository
    }
}
```

does anyone have an idea, it would be very much appreciated!
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content (such as error messages). Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please add error text (stack trace)

Comment: I am sorry! I will do it right away!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all the `buildscript` block in the top level file and add in the `plugins` the google-services plugin:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.0' apply false
    
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.3.13' apply false
}
```